# Are EIP's required for internet traffic?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, eip

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I can't find any definitive answers.  I setup a VPC with a private subnet and a public subnet.  THe private subnet has a NAT'd instance to route for internet traffic.  The public subnet is configured to go out of the IGW.

-I created a Bastion host to login into SSH
-I created Test instance on private subnet and connect from Bastion Host.  Because of the route to the NAT instance and port 80/443 is allowed and ICMP, i can ping and access files on the internet.
-I create instance on public subnet without EIP.  Since it has a route to the IGW, shouldn't I have internet access?  I created a test security group to allow all traffic from all sources and i still can't ping or get http links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A public subnet instance with a public DNS name should be accessible over the internet provided you have right VPC security group configured. You do not need an EIP.

Public DNS name of EC2 instance changes when you stop and start the instance. to avoid this, you can assign an EIP to the instance so that the IP address remains same across the instance stop/start cycles.

You need to answer these questions:

1. Does your public subnet instance has a public DNS hostname? Run `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname` on your instance to see the public DNS hostname.
2. Do you have VPC security group configured properly to allow incoming internet access ?

Comment: When I run step 1 on an EC2 instance in the public subnet with no EIP, I get a 404 error.  I'm unable to ping 169.254.169.254 and I have double checked and made sure the security group is correct.  My EC2 instances are not launching with a Public DNS hostname.  I went to my VPC configuration and enabled it and relaunched a micro Instance and it still wasn't working.  I looked and realized none of them had public DNS hostnames and went through the launch configuration and saw that I was not enabling the public DNS option :(  Thanks!  It's working now :)

Comment: On Stackoverflow, If an answer provides resolution to you, then [you should accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it and optionally [you should upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it.

Comment: Done :)  quick follow up question: I wanted to confirm because I can't find it, but I CANNOT enable the DNS public host name AFTER I've launched an instance?  It has to be enabled from the very beginning?

Comment: Correct. You can't. Please read [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html). It has a detailed explanation of EC2 Instance IP Addressing and should clarify a lot of your concerns.